# Cannot use formdata with safari, what is next best?

Tags: javascript, safari, form-data

I am using `formData()`, but safari does not yet support it so I must use something else. What is the next best solution to not using formdata.

```
let form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  let data = new FormData(form);
  let obj;
  data.forEach((value, key) => {
   obj[key] = value;
  })
});
```

Comment: Just read the input directly until they support get() ??

Comment: Safari has supported FormData since 2014

Comment: @Quentin it has basic support, missing a lot of functionality unless something has changed recently and I have not been paying attention.

Comment: .get is not a function in safari, along with a lot of other formdata functions.